# How do I disable context menu for UISearchBar

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

I need to disable the context menu showing in the UISearchBar

Currently I tried sub-clasing UISearchBar and overriding canPerformAction:withSender: as below, but without success. What is the best method of doing the same?

Header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomSearchBar : UISearchBar

@end
```

And implementation

```
#import "CustomSearchBar.h"

@implementation CustomSearchBar

- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    return NO;
}

@end
```

Comment: What exactly is the context menu you're trying to hide?

Comment: Cut, copy, paste that shows up by default on touch and hold.

Comment: I'm not sure thats possible, I believe it is a system feature that comes up any time you have an editable text field

Comment: This is the way it is done for UITextField. Checked it and it works fine, but doesn't work for UISearchBar.